# Considering buying a keyboard but need advice

Tags: keyboard, digital-piano

I've always wanted to learn how to play the piano but I've never actually tried. I'm thinking about buying a 61 key keyboard (I found one used for a great price) to see if I can learn how to play and if I'd ever want to buy a real piano.

I'm just wondering if learning to use a keyboard would be similar to a piano. I don't want to invest a lot into something I'm not sure I'll like but I do want to try and am not interested in lessons at this time.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It'll be close enough if you are just starting.  The main differences would be the sound, an acoustic piano will sound warmer than a synth piano or an electric sound and the dynamics might not exist (I had an electric piano and this was the case).

Comment: I typed Keyboard for learning piano in the search bar and found many similar questions with good answers including [link](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/14152/16897) and [link](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/10175/16897)